# How can i change the activity background using two buttons?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, background

What can I do to change the drawable of a background switching between two buttons. For example, I want that when I click button_1 the drawable change to the image "background_1" and when I click button_2, it changes to the image "background_2"

Thanks to all of you!

PD: Sorry for my bad english, i'm catalan

Comment: just set a listener and get the background and change it. This should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
button1.setOnClicklistener(this);
button2.setOnClicklistener(this);

public void (View view){
    If(view.getId==R.id.button1){
your_root_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_1;
  } else {
     your_root_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_2;
     }
}
```

Make sure your activity implements `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: But this would change the background of the activity or the background of the button? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: See my edited answer. Glad it helped

Comment: Thank you very much, but what is the root view?

Comment: Post the layout you used for the setContentView. The rootView is the view underwhich the two buttons are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your button background:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button1.setBackGroundResource(R.drawable.background_1);
    }
 });

button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button2.setBackGroundResource(R.drawable.background_2);
    }
 });
```